# View totals not working correctly for task list in 2013

Tags: 2013, view, task-list

The issue I'm having is that the *Totals* section in the task list view settings isn't updating with the filters of the view.  It is working in a custom list as well as a task list in SharePoint Online.  This is only happening to task lists in 2013 as of right now.

**Settings I am modifying located in the list view settings:**

[image]

In this example I am trying to see the sum of the *Cost* field.  I want to see this in relation to my current view.

**All tasks:**

[image]

**Alpha tasks:**

[image]

You can see that the sum does not get filtered along with the list.  I have a custom list in the same site that this is done in and it works as expected.  The *Alpha* view shows up as *$200*.

Has anyone else noticed this or come up with a solution?  I feel like it's a bug being that it works as expected in custom lists and in SharePoint Online task lists.

Comment: you are facing the issue on-premise sharepoint 2013?

Comment: Yes, on-premises SP 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, you need to install the latest CU for SharePoint 2013.  KB3114345 fixed the issue for me

Comment: Please don't give that short answers. And at least give the specific CU which fixed it for you.

Comment: KB3114345 fixed the issue for me

Comment: @JaneBlack You can edit your answer and add the KB which fixed the issue, and you will have a better answer. Thank you